# Share volume across multiple containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a situation in which container runs a `npm run dev` so this is just `rollup -cw`, so we're waiting for frontend file changes and creating a bundle. Now the problem is that I have two containers, one is for frontend and the other is for backend. And when I use docker-compose to mix all containers together, these two doesn't share the same volume. So backend doesn't know when the bundle has been created or updated. Also I must ensure that when any changes happen (in fronted) the bundle also must be updated in the host files? And if I'm getting everything right, if I would use named volume then the host files will not be effected. What's the other choice?

This is my root dir:

```
- frontend
- backend
- docker-compose.yml
```

The bundle is being created to backend static files dir. And the backend doesn't know that the bundle is updated or etc. All containers are isolated, right?

```
frontend:
    tty: true
    restart: unless-stopped
    stdin_open: true
    build: ./frontend
    container_name: frontend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/frontend # Ensure that npm run dev would catch new changes
  django:
    build: ./web
    ports:
      - 5050:5050
    restart: always
    container_name: django
    command: [django, runserver, 0.0.0.0:5050]
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    depends_on:
      - frontend
    volumes:
      - .:/werent # Update the container with local changes
```

This is the rollup.config.js:

```
   input: "./main.ts",
    output: {
      format: "iife", // Immediately Invoked Function Expression
      file: "../web/static/dist/bundle.js",
    },
```

How should I make this work? What's the best practice for connecting these two and also updating local files?

Comment: Is the `frontend` container actually serving anything, or is it just building files that the `django` container serves as static content?  If the latter, I'd build the frontend in a multi-stage build, remove the dedicated `frontend` container, and remove the `volumes:` that hide the image code.

Comment: frontend is just building the bundle.js in which there's all the code for frontend and just places it in the backend static directory. In which the bundle is later access via base.html template via static files

Comment: And I'm still confused if it's the right way to do it. I mean building the bundle inside the backend dir and not in the frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clarify that the `frontend` container is just building the static assets for the `django` application.  It doesn't actually need a running container for this.  A better approach is to use a *multi-stage* build; this uses a `node` image to compile the front-end, and then `COPY --from` that into the actual Django image.

This would roughly look like:

```bash
FROM node:lts AS frontend
WORKDIR /frontend
COPY frontend/package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY frontend/ ./
RUN npm build

FROM python:3.11
WORKDIR /werent
COPY web/requirements.txt ./
...
COPY --from=frontend /frontend/dist/ static/dist/
...
CMD ["django", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:5050"]
```

One detail to note here is that you're accessing files from both the `frontend` and `web` directories.  This means the Docker build context directory needs to be a parent of these directories, and the left-hand side of `COPY` needs to mention which subdirectory to use.

In the Compose file, then, it's important that you do **not** have `volumes:` that hide the application directory.  Since the frontend is only injected in the Dockerfile and isn't necessarily built on your host, a bind mount would hide the copy of the frontend application that the image builds.  You also don't need most of the other options you show in the Compose file.  It should be enough to say

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  # no frontend: container
  django:
    build: ./web
    ports:
      - 5050:5050
    restart: always
    # no container_name:, command:, tty:, stdin_open:, volumes:
```

The other important detail is that you can still use this Docker-based setup even if you normally use host tools for development.  You can for example launch this container but then use a Webpack dev server without Docker for live development on the frontend; or you could work on the Python source code locally in a non-Docker virtual environment, run `pytest` locally, and run `docker-compose up --build` only when you're ready to do final integration testing.

Comment: So if I got this correctly, the best thing would be to actually not use `npm run dev` in the development with docker and just run it locally? Let's say for production that we can maybe just use a multi-stage build to create the bundle and just copy it to the backend right?

Comment: Just as you made an example above, this would fit the production requirements because it's not watching for any file changes in frontend it just makes a bundle and copies it.

Comment: Right, the setup I show here would definitely be suitable for use in production.  You would only need to get the image on to the target server (maybe referencing a registry with a Compose `image:`) and you would not need to separately copy any of the source code.

Comment: Thank you very much for a detailed answer. So the only problem with my code was that both containers were isolated and backend was not detecting any changes due to this reason?